# Nativescript get properties from child element in ng-repeat

Tags: angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I've got a dynamically generated checklist in Angular/Nativescript like so:

```
<StackLayout *ngIf="assessment">
         <StackLayout *ngFor="let instance_item of assessment.exam_instance_items; let i= index">
               <ns-examitem [attr.id]="'item_'+instance_item.id" [assessmentitem]="instance_item"
                  (changeEvent)="validateExam($event)"></ns-examitem>
          </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

where the examitem has a radio button control bound to a value

(in examitem.component.ts- the child component)

```
// get the values out
   public selectedvalue: string = '';

   // tell the world something's changed, trigger validation
  @Output() changeEvent = new EventEmitter();

  changeCheckedRadio(radioOption: RadioOption): void {
    // uncheck all other options
    this.radioOptions.forEach(option => {
      if (option.value !== radioOption.value) {
        option.selected = false;
      } else {
        option.selected = true;
        this.selectedvalue = option.value;
        this.assessmentitem.selectedValue = this.selectedvalue;
      }
    });
    // tell the world the value has changed
    console.log('ExamitemComponent.Radio option changed to:' + this.selectedvalue)
    this.changeEvent.emit();
  }
```

I'm really struggling getting the selectedvalue out of the examitem components in the parent component. I can get the component reference by ID, but can't read the value.

Anyone able to help?

Comment: `this.changeEvent.emit(this.selectedvalue)` in your component you can get the value using `(changeEvent)="log($event)";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to emit the value you want to get in parent component like so

```
this.changeEvent.emit(this.selectedvalue);
```

Then in parent component you can use this value in the validateExam function .

Comment: I want to iterate through the exam items though. In some cases, an item will need to be hidden or shown based on the answer of another item.

Comment: That's a complete different matter , need to see parent component code where items are generated .

Comment: @Wilheim You would have access to all elements once you are in `validateExam` event where you could decide which items to hide / show from `exam_instance_items` based on changed value.

Comment: This is what I've eventually gone with. I thought I'd be able to access/read some property in the element, but I suspect Angular doesn't work that way.
The strategy that works (inelegantly) is to:
- Have some property of the object I'm binding to the exam item (instance_item) like 'visible' that shows/hides the item
- Emit the selected value (answer) of the exam item, along with some identifier of what exam item was modified
- Use that answer to update the 'visible' property of the object I'm binding to that needs to be hidden or shown based on the emitted answer.